# Split big shinydashboard app into pieces

Tags: r, file, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm quite new to `shiny` and `shinydashboard`. My first application has grown to a size that I would like to refactor it into pieces as hinted http://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html here:

```
dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody()
)
```

It should be a fairly simple task. However, I could not find any examples on how to split my app into multiple files, and I am not sure what is the best way to do this.

I could not get it to work so far: I tried calling `source("myBody.R")` within each part.

Comment: What you're trying to do makes sense, so the error must be in the details. Please share a concrete example of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Take a look at @Shape's strategy in https://stackoverflow.com/a/33584292/4606130.

**server.R:**

```
    library(shiny)
    source('sub_server_functions.R')

    function(input, output, session) {
        subServerFunction1(input, output, session)
        subServerFunction2(input, output, session)
        subServerFunction3(input, output, session) 
    }
```

Other ideas are:

2. Put your data calls and constants in a **global.R** which can be shared by both your ui and server.R file. Look at http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html
3. Look at the **new Module approach** to Shiny. I am still getting to grips with this but looks promising to rationalise. See http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html

An example of a flex dashboard `.Rmd` file looks pretty thin after this!

````
---
title: "screenR"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---

```{r}
# include the module
source("screenrdata.R")
```

Charts
======

### Screening Scatter

```{r}

# call the module
xyUI("id1")
callModule(screenchart, "id1")
```
````

Answer (score 4):

You can have some UI code in a different file and then include it in your main UI with

```
source("file.R", local=TRUE)$value
```

You can see more details on this shiny article  http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html