# How to manage my R code in a shiny or shinydashboard app?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have made a shinydashboard app which has now quite an amount of lines of code, and I am wondering if there are ways to split the code into different . R files. I have seen a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30560405/3902976), but the answer does not help (especially it says nothing about the code in the server part of the app).

For the ui part, I have created functions called `header`, `sidebar`, and `body`, and then I merely write

```
ui <- dashboardPage(header(), sidebar(), body())
```

It works well, and it still works if the functions `header`, `sidebar`, and `body` need to have arguments.

For the server part, I don't think a similar strategy can be applied. I am wondering whether "local" server functions (one per menu item for instance) could be written, and then reunified into one central server function.

Do you think something like that is doable? More generally, thank you for your advice and ideas that could make my code more manageable.

Comment: This question should probably be removed since it is too general. Check out the talk on modularizing shiny apps. For example I just wrote functions that shortened my app.R by hundreds of lines, but it doesn't necessarily apply to your app. But yeah you should be using `source("HelperFunctions.R")` inside your app.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this meets your requirement, you can create different files and do the required computations in those files and save all the objects (data frames or lists or literally anything) into .Rds file using `saveRDS()` in R and then load that file into server.R using `loadRDS()` which will have all your saved objects. You can find the documentation [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readRDS.html).

Then simply use those objects by calling the names as they are saved earlier. Most of the complex Shiny apps use `global.R` file (just a general convention, you can use any name) to do the heavy computations and follow the above approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use `source` to call other R files in server.R:

1. Use `source` as you usually do in regular R outside any reactive functions.
2. Use `source("xxxxx", local=T)` when you want to use it inside a reactive function so the r codes you called will run every time this piece of reactive codes are activated.

Answer (score 2):

For the server side:

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
source('sub_server_functions.R')

function(input, output, session) {
    subServerFunction1(input, output, session)
    subServerFunction2(input, output, session)
    subServerFunction3(input, output, session) 
}
```

This has worked for me, it's possible you'll need to pass more variables to the subserver functions. But the scoping of the reactive output appears to allow this.

sub_server_functions.R:

```
subserverfunction1 <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$checkboxGroupInput1 <- renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput('test1','test1',choices = c(1,2,3))
 })
}

subserverfunction2 <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$checkboxGroupInput2 <- renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput('test2','test2',choices = c(1,2,3))
 })
}

subserverfunction3 <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$checkboxGroupInput3 <- renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput('test3','test3',choices = c(1,2,3))
 })
}
```